# Get download link of file certain app is downloading

Tags: windows, file, web, download, sniffer

I have an application that downloading some file from web.
How can I check the link from where this file is downloading.

I think I should use some sniffer for this but not sure which.
Tried Wireshark and Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4 but no luck. To many packages or some strange data inside 'em.
I'm on Windows 10 x64 btw.

Will appreciate any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately questions like these are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Oveflow, and therefore should be asked here:
[SuperUser](https://superuser.com) or here: [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

Try TCPView from Microsoft sysinternals

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview

#### EDIT:

Does not seems to work with chrome. I tried downloading a 2GB file to have time to check and I cannot find the URL visible in chrome downloader in TCPView. I seem to get the IP However. There is a chrome instance receiving big amounts of packets with only an IP showing